# Strtok(): Tokenizing string

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error that says "No matching function for call to 'strtok'". I'm not very good at coding and am confused D:

Example of line from file I'm reading from:
Wilco   Wilco   2009    Nonesuch Records    11  58  Rock

```
int find_oldest_album(Album **& albums, int num_of_albums){
    string line;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("/Users/ms/Desktop/albums.txt");
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, line, '\n');
        char * artist_name;
        char artist_name = strtok(line, '\t');
        char * title_name;
        title_name = strtok(NULL, '\t');
        char  * release_year;
        release_year = strtok(NULL, '\t');
    }


    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: You can actually use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for tokenization too.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` function may be applied only to character arrays. It is a C standard function. If you want to parse an object of type `std::string` the same way as by using `strtok` when you should use standard stream class `std::istringstream` declared in header `<sstream>`

For example

```
#include <sstream>

//...

std::string line;
std::getline( fin, line, '\n' );

std::istringstream is( line );

std::string artist_name;
std::getline( is, artist_name, '\t' );
```

As for your code then it contains numerous errors.

For example in these two statements

```
   char * artist_name;
   char artist_name = strtok(line, '\t');
```

there are three errors. You are redeclaring name artist_name, function strtok may not be used with objects of type `std::string` and the second parameter of function `strtok`, delimiter, has to be specified as a character string, it has type `const char *`.

Comment: That's a horrible way of doing it.  Why abuse `std::getline`, when `std::find` works just as well.

Comment: @James Kanze  It is very aclear approach. It is using std:;find is horrible because in fact there is nothing is being found. There is being entered data fields. And your approach is simply wrong in case when the input contains different  types of data for example numbers, strings, bool and so on.

Comment: It's obfuscation.  The name of the function is `getline`, not search in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is a broken C function, and should not be used.  It requires a
writable C string (*not* `std::string`), and it has static state, which
can easily be corrupted.

If you're lines have a standard separator, such as the tab character,
it's easy to write a function to break them up into fields:

```
std::vector<std::string>
split( std::string const& line )
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string::const_iterator end = line.end();
    std::string::const_iterator current = line.start();
    std::string::const_iterator next = std::find( current, end, '\t' );
    while ( next != end ) {
        results.push_back( std::string( current, next ) );
        current = next + 1;
        next = std::find( current, end, '\t' );
    }
    results.push_back( std::string( current, end ) );
    return results;
}
```

More generally, for any parsing problem, just iterate through the
string, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution using C++ is outlined by vlad from Mosco in his answer. To resolve error "No matching functio  for call to 'strtok'" you need to include header file as follows:

```
#include<cstring>
```